# Can not change page with script a href = #page-index on jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I build hybrid applications to use your android with cordova one page, I try to replace the page with the id and its url, but it turned out to not be.

```
$("#listview").append("<li><a href='#page-sampling-pm?id_pm="+id_pm+"&nama_project="+nama_project+"' data-transition='slide'><h2>"+ nama_project + "</h2></a></li>");
```

if it can not is there another way??

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="listview">
<ul id="list">

</ul
</div>
var id_pm=123;
var nama_project="myproject";
var list="<li><a href='#page-sampling-pm?id_pm="+id_pm+"&nama_project="+nama_project+"' data-transition='slide'><h2>"+ nama_project + "</h2></a></li>"
$("#listview").append(list);
```

Comment: I assumed the id_pm and nama_project

Comment: thank @Ray, its change page but in the url bar only `http://localhost/web/index.html#page-sampling-pm` show not `http://localhost/web/index.html#page-sampling-pm?id_pm=123&&nama_project=myproject`